# Is data normalization necessary when your data has the same scale in a multi criteria decision making context?

Tags: dataset, normalization, excel

So I am exploring different MCDM techniques and I know that data normalization techniques might have different influence on the final ranking of the alternatives depending on the MCDM method used.

I am in a scenario where I used a linguistic scale (O to 3 with 0 being poor and 3 being excellent) to score my criteria. I am using the TOPSIS method to rank my 3 alternatives. Logically, if my data is already on the same scale, I should skip the normalization step however, by curiosity, I normalized my data using vector normalization and I got a different ranking of my alternatives. Can anyone explain why ?

Without normalization:
[image: Data + Ranking without noramlization]

With Normalization:
[image]

Can anyone help? Thanks!